# Obtaining / iterating through data in the laravel service container via app()

Tags: laravel

If I do `dd(app())` within my app I can see data that is useful to me within the #resolved branch of the service container object that is returned to screen.

A really silly question though; what is the easiest way of iterating through that data ?   I've tried things like app()->resolved which don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `$resolved` array is protected for something, however you can use reflection to get it:

```
$rp = new \ReflectionProperty('\Illuminate\Foundation\Application', 'resolved');
$rp->setAccessible(true);
dd($rp->getValue(app()));
```

Comment: Thanks @Berto99 but I get...

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ReflectionProperty' not found

Comment: @AdamJones since you are inside a namespace, you should add a `\` at the beginning (edited the answer)